# Removing SBJson library from Wikitude

Tags: xcode, sbjson, wikitude

In my app I have to use two different Augmented Reality SDKs. Wikitude and another one. The problem is that I get `duplicate symbols`errors when I want to build the app. After some research I found out that both frameworks contain the SBJson library. So I have to delete this file from Wikitude but I don't know how.

Has anyone an idea how to find and remove that library from Wikitude?

Answer (score 0):

please drop us an email to developer@wikitude.com and we can support you with your issue.

Cheers
Phil

Disclaimer: Working for Wikitude.